# Transparent layouts for grid view in android apps

Tags: android, gridview

I am working on a sample grid view in android. Can someone guide me how can I create a transparent grid view. I need to give a 3d effect to each grid item and also I need to make the grid view layout a transparent one. I must be able to view the background through this grid view.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You could set the alpha by `gridview.setAlpha(alpha)`

Answer (score 0):

If you define your grid view in xml, set background color to #00000000

Comment: you should use color code android:background="@android:color/transparent"
rather than hex color code :)

Comment: You got solution i still facing problem for this, have any solution?